# Do I need to keep app/assets/config/manifest.js in my Rails 7 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I had an old Rails 5 app (with bootstrap via webpacker), and I spent my whole day today in migrating this to Rails 7. I was quite happy that I finally can get rid of webpacker initially, but I was confused with so many options out there, and I finally get it work with the following post.

https://eagerworks.com/blog/import-maps-in-rails-7

However, I found the following file in my folder.

`app/assets/config/manifest.js`

it contains the following code

```
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
```

I believe that it was generated via my prior trials (esbundling, I guess). Can I safely delete this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuh-uh, can't delete it.

For importmaps it should look like this:

```js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
```

Assuming your javascript is in `app/javascript` directory. If it's in `app/assets/javascripts` then you should have this:

```js
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

Double check and make sure you're getting digested urls:

```bash
$ bin/importmap json
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-37f365cbecf1fa2810a8303f4b6571676fa1f9c56c248528bc14ddb857531b95.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js"
  }
}
```

`sprockets` uses that file to precompile files in production and it will break if you remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I found that the manifest.js is used by Sprocket (particularly from version 4). More detailed information is found : https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs

I was confused because I still have files from previous Sprocket(app/assets/javascripts/application.js and app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss).